# Jackson deserializer unit test

Tags: java, jackson

I've written a deserializer to check if the class field is of a certain custom type, if not then convert it. Below is my code.

```
    public MyClassA deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        ObjectCodec codec = jsonParser.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = codec.readTree(jsonParser);

        final JsonNode classAField = node.get("classAField");

        if (classAField != null) {
          return codec.treeToValue(node,classAField.class);
        }
        //convert it and return;

    }
```

I want to write a test case for this and I did something like this:

```
public class classADeserializerTest {

    classADeserializer deserializer;
    JsonParser parser;
    DeserializationContext context;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        deserializer = new MyClassADeserializer();
        parser = Mockito.mock(JsonParser.class);
        context = Mockito.mock(DeserializationContext.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testDeserialize() throws IOException {
        String json = "{}";
        //String json = "{\"classAField\":{}}";
        JsonNode json1 = JsonUtils.jsonToObject(json, JsonNode.class);


        Mockito.when(parser.getCodec().readTree(parser)).thenReturn(json1);

        MyClassA result = deserializer.deserialize(parser, context);

        Assert.assertEquals(result,MyClassA.builder().options(Collections.emptyList()).build());
    }
}
```

I'm now to jackson and kinda blocked here. When I run the test I get NUllPointerException at line `JsonNode json1 = JsonUtils.jsonToObject(json, JsonNode.class);`

The **JsonUtils.jsonToObject()** uses Jackson's ObjectMapper 'convertValue' method for typecasting.

Inputs on this would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's unclear what JsonUtils is being used. Without seeing the imports, it could be something you wrote yourself.

Comment: The JsonUtils.jsonToObject() uses Jackson's ObjectMapper 'convertValue' method for typecasting. Mentioned the same in the description above.

Comment: Why do you mock `JsonParser` and don't inject a real instance of it?

Comment: I'm not sure how to inject JsonParser directly with the test data in it.

Comment: @Nikhil How would you use your deserializer in "real code"? Test it like you would use it in production. You probably set up an `ObejctMapper`, then add modules, then pass it a JSON string. Do the same in your tests